# Initialize the socketIO too slow, using python socketIO-client package

Tags: python, socket.io, client

I use socketIO-client package in python for testing my server code.
It is a simple client, but it always takes about 1 min to run the following line:

```
socketIO = SocketIO('localhost',3003)
```

I wonder how to solve this problem?

I use eventlet and didn't install socketIO-client in virtual environment.
Would it cause this problem?

```
from socketIO_client import SocketIO, BaseNamespace
from datetime import datetime

Devices = {}

temp_time = datetime.now()

class Namespace(BaseNamespace):
    def on_connect(self):
        print('[Connected]')
        for device in Devices:
            self.emit('register', device)
            time.sleep(1)

def funcA():
    do something

def funcB():
    do something

print '1:', datetime.now()-temp_time
socketIO = SocketIO('localhost', 3003)
print '2:', datetime.now()-temp_time
socketIO.define(Namespace)

socketIO.on('eventA', funcA)
socketIO.on('eventB', funcB)
socketIO.wait()
```

The output of the client part:

```
1: 0:00:00.000074
DEBUG:root:localhost:3003/socket.io [transport selected] xhr-polling
DEBUG:root:localhost:3003/socket.io [heartbeat reset]
2: 0:01:00.019828
DEBUG:root:localhost:3003/socket.io [socket.io packet received] 0
[Connected]
```

Answer (score -1):

My Python socket ioclient connects pretty quickly to an external node.js server. 
This may be a routing/DNS problem
Localhost can exhibit strange routing behaviour sometimes.
use 127.0.0.1 not localhost as the url to eliminate routing /DNS timeouts